# Understanding a step in Wikipedia's proof of the Uniform Boundedness Principle

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm struggling to understand a step in Wikipedia's [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Theorem) of the Uniform Boundedness Principle. It is claimed that each

$$X_n:=\left\{x\in X \ : \ \sup_{T\in F}||T(x)|| \le n \right\}$$

is closed. Why is this so?

Comment: 1) You changed $\leq $ to $<$ ;  2) Use the fact that intersection of closed sets is always closed and $\sup_{T\in F}||T(x)|| \leq  n $ iff $||T(x)|| \leq n $ for each $T$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see, but what are the sets that form the intersection here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $T\in F$ is continuous. Also note that,
$$
X_n = \bigcap_{T \in F} \underbrace{\{x \in X: \|Tx\| \leq n\}}_{:= A_n}.
$$
Now let $T\in F$ be arbitrary and let $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A_n$ that converges to some $x \in X$. We have
$$
\|Tx\| = \|T(\lim_{k \to \infty}x_k)\| = \|\lim_{k \to \infty}Tx_k\| = \lim_{k \to \infty}\|Tx_k\| \leq n,
$$
where I have used the continuity of $T$ and the norm. Hence, $x \in A_n$ and thus $A_n$ is closed. This implies that $X_n$ is closed since it is an intersection of closed sets. Hope this helps!